# Django generates a new session ID on every API call

Tags: django, session, sessionid

I have a Django back-end that feeds a front-end through a REST API. I am facing an issue with Django generating a **new** session ID on **every** API call.

I am testing with Chrome and I noticed that the `sessionid` cookie is only created if I run the webserver locally. The problem occurs when I go online.

Here is a couple of useful settings to help troubleshooting:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...
}
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    ...
)
if not local:
    SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.my-domain.com'
```

Any setting that was not mentioned above should be considered to be set to the default value (Django 1.6).

Comment: do you see the client receiving and transmitting the session cookie?

Comment: I'm using the 'Resources' panel of the chrome toolbox (Ctrl+Shift+C) to check the cookies that are currently stored (is it OK?), and on the client side I'm not able to see the `sessionid` cookie when I go on production. The same check on a local server works fine (i.e., I see this `sessionid` cookie and my `Session` table does not blow up the database).

Comment: you should also be able to see the cookie on the request (net panel probably, don't have chrome out of hand right now), if you don't see the cookie the fault is probably on SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN

Comment: From the network panel I can see that the request sends no cookie but the response has a "Set-Cookie" header with a `sessionid` field populated with a session ID and a `Domain` field set to my domain. So it *should* work. What's the problem with my `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`?

Comment: none, as the cookie is correctly set., does the api calls send the cookie?

Comment: Well in fact the request (API call) sends **no** cookie. Then the response from the API call just **tries** to set a new cookie by adding this "Set-Cookie" header to the HttpResponse, but fails for some reason because subsequent API calls would lead to the same issue (i.e., the request not having the session cookie attached). As a result you can send loads of API calls and never be able to properly set the session cookie, even though the API response provides the needed information.

Comment: So SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN is set to default None on your local? What if you just do the same for production?

Comment: It gives the same behaviour.